# How do DSLRs figure out what aperture to select in P mode?

Tags: dslr, aperture, program-mode

In program mode, DSLRs adjust not only the ISO and the shutter speed, but also the aperture.

The aperture has a huge impact in some situations. For example, when shooting a close subject in front of a meaningless background, the aperture must be large so the background is blurred as much as possible; on the other hand, when shooting landscape, nobody wants a ƒ/1.4. How do cameras determine the aperture to set? More precisely:

- Are there some general rules applied by most brands?
- If not, given some camera model as an example, what rules are applied by this camera?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is called the ***"program line"***. Imagine a grid labeled *aperture* in one direction and *shutter speed* the other way, as in the "[exposure rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW0pI.png)" in the middle of [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle#12441). There are many different combinations which *could* produce the same exposure, and **the program line is literally the line drawn on the graph to represent what a given program actually chooses for a certain lens**. If you add in auto-ISO, it becomes [three-dimensional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG84x.png) but is still basically the same.

In older cameras, the line was simple, and the desired exposure value was all that was considered. If a camera decided to give you f/4 and ¹⁄₅₀₀th to hit EV 13 (at ISO 100) in a given situation, it would do the same thing in *any* situation with the same target exposure. Modern cameras now have algorithms that result in *multiple* lines (or, a complex polyhedron within the cube, if you want to get all mathy), depending on factors like lens focal length, flash, user-selected parameters, and maybe even image stabilization.

These days, the exact program is *secret sauce* and there's no general answer; each brand (and possibly even each model from the same brand) has a different algorithm. As an example, my Pentax camera offers the following choices, which influence which program line is used:

- **Normal** — Pentax calls this "Basic Program Automatic Exposure", and it tends towards middling values for everything.
- **Hi-speed Priority** — The documentation says "prioritizes high shutter speeds" (helpful, guys). Based on experience, the basic program for shutter speed takes the focal length into account (faster speeds for longer lenses), and I'm not sure if this acts as a weighting of that factor or if it has a pre-set idea of "high" in this mode.
- **DOF Priority (shallow)** — Pretty self-explanatory: the program attempts to hold aperture as wide as possible, unless it can't to make the exposure work. Shutter speed is informed by the focal length, and how that and ISO are adjusted depend on the auto-ISO setting (see below).
- **DOF Priority (deep)** — The opposite, of course.
- **MTF Priority** — When used with a Pentax lens with electronic coupling, prioritizes the lens's technically-best "sweet spot" (see this question on [MTF charts](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/how-do-i-interpret-an-mtf-chart))

And to add complication, there's also an **Auto**, which has no technical documentation, but presumably chooses one of the above programs based on... who knows, actually. Maybe focus mode, probably the metering. Maybe the current zodiac sign.

If you have auto-ISO enabled (a separate choice from *that* "Auto"), there's a complex interaction with the program mode choices and the settings for auto-ISO, which can be "slow", "standard", or "fast". If you have it set to "slow", something else — shutter or ISO, depending on how that fits the program mode choice — will be increased first. If you have it set to "fast", raising ISO is the preference, and "standard" is somewhere in between. The upper and lower bounds of automatic ISO are chosen in by yet another set of customizable parameters.

Lower-model cameras will just keep everything secret — although "scene modes" like *sports* or *landscape* will serve a similar function. Other high-end cameras may have similar complex parameters to tweak, although in general they have fewer options than my example camera.

There's a detailed discussion of Canon's program mode [in this Photography On the Net thread](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=796328), and Canon officially provides a [nice explanation of how the basic algorithm works for their older cameras](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/camera_settings/shooting_modes.do), including a [handy chart](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/files/education/infobank/camera_settings/shooting_modes/caption_004_thumb.jpg):

[image: canon program line chart]

It's almost easier to *describe* than to read the chart, though: as brightness increases from EV -5, the aperture stays wide open and shutter speed increases until stopping down is an option, at which point shutter speed and aperture are both reduced evenly until the minimum aperture of the lens is reached, at which point it's back to the shutter.

Canon doesn't publish charts like this for their current cameras. The referenced thread suggests that the basic program is the same with auto-ISO enabled, and Canon does not provide official explanation for what logic *that* mode uses, although anecdotal evidence suggests it attempts to keep the shutter speed fast enough to match the focal length.

Nikon also does not offer many choices on their current DSLRs, although  [some Nikon film cameras offered choices](http://mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/nikonf4/exposurecontrol/index.htm) between *normal* and *high speed* programs. Now, from the entry-level models to the high-end, the `P` mode is a black box with regard to shutter speed and aperture, and ISO is controlled via a minimum shutter speed — if the regular program would require a shutter speed below that, and auto-ISO is on, ISO is increased instead. This has some advantages (particularly when you want to control subject motion), but doesn't appear to take lens focal length into account (although the program line is probably already adjusted for that), and the `Min Shutter Spd` option is buried several levels deep in the "Shooting Menu".

With some experimentation with P mode, one could reverse-engineer the program mode logic, but I think mostly, Canon and Nikon expect you to move on to the more-controlled semi-auto modes once you care about stuff like that.

Pentax, though, goes out of their way to make the automation accessible and flexible. On my camera, a Pentax K-7, and on other recent Pentax DSLRs, the "program mode" is easily selectable via the "info" button menu, where it's both discoverable and quick to use if you really want to learn and use the ins and outs of the different modes. A screen capture:

[image: Program Line Info-Button UI]

And ISO is similar, although actually changing the auto-ISO parameters is one level deeper:

[image: Auto ISO Parameters UI]

<sub>(An aside: if you just want to change the current ISO, the camera has a dedicated button for that. It can also be changed through the Info menu if you want or desire, *without* going into this submenu.)</sub>

**In general, though, if you really care about getting a certain aperture, that's what Aperture Priority mode is there for.** My informal impression (see for example [many of the answers to this related question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18668/is-there-a-good-use-for-program-exposure-modes)) is that aperture priority is the most commonly used automatic mode for more technically-inclined photographers. It's interesting that Pentax has chosen to work on providing advanced options here, but I think the bigger companies might be right in considering it not particularly important.

One *could* try to remember all of the complicated interactions above and choose the intersection that best matches your intentions for a given situation — or you can just, y'know, choose directly. That actually seems easier than all the automation.

I leave my camera's `P` mode set to MTF Priority — there, the automation is actually doing something useful for me, since the camera knows the MTF for my various lenses at different apertures, and I don't carry that in my head.

Comment: In the old days, camera manufacturers published their program curves. These curves show the set of all possible aperture/shutter speed combinations that the P mode can chose from. The curve provides only one choice for each EV value.

Comment: @Edgar: now, it's more complicated. Not only is it three-dimensional with the addition of auto-ISO, but the curve is altered by the various custom settings, which in my example mean there's fifteen different 3D curves.

Comment: With the low cost high tech stuff we have today, a camera could smartly sense things like how much you are shaking or moving, or how much you have zoomed (read from lens already for EXIF), and adjust accordingly (e.g. faster shutter for more shaking).

Comment: @Skaperen — the program mode on my camera _does_ take into account the focal length when choosing shutter speed. It's possible that movement could be one of the factors considered by the Auto setting, but I doubt it.

Comment: @mattdm May I ask Pentax camera this is? are they part of *icon* modes or buried within configurations?

Comment: @rockacola — It's a Pentax K-7. You can reach and change these settings quiet quickly through the "Info button" menu page.

Comment: From my observation, pentax auto iso slow is half the speed of normal and fast is double the speed of normal. Different program lines will follow different paths, but auto iso setting always doubles the speed from slow to normal and again from normal to fast.

Comment: Also re: Nikon, in P mode you can use the rear dial to alter the balance between aperture/shutter anyway so you can override the default balance.

Comment: @JamesSnell Same in Pentax -- by default, turning the rear dial changes the aperture and kicks you into the Av program, and turning the front dial changes the shutter and puts you in Tv. Green button resets to P.

Comment: IIRC (as I've not used P in a long time) the Nikon method retains the 'balance' rather than kicking you into other modes.  So say you've dialled in +1 stop aperture (so -1 Shutter to keep balance) then it'll hold that relationship as the values change - if that makes sense?

Comment: @JamesSnell Yes, that's basically the same, although the different cameras might treat auto ISO differently.

Comment: @mattdm They're not just three dimensional. They're at least (*n*-2) dimensional where *n* is the number of variables considered. In the old days we got two dimensional charts (that were actually flat depictions of three-dimensional models) from four variables: EV, Tv, Av, and FL. Now with variables for EV, Tv, Av, ISO, FL, focus distance, IS on/off/mode, flash on or off, which metering mode is selected, which AF mode is selected, MTF, etc. the models are getting way too complex to print on a 2-D piece of paper. I also suspect some companies consider their models as trade secrets.

Comment: Canon doesn't offer as much flexibility for **P** mode, but look at AF modes! There are manuals several hundred pages long just covering the options for the AF systems in Canon's most advanced bodies. These bodies have six basic AF "cases" with at least three adjustable variables (with 3-5 levels per variable) for each case. Then there's AF/shutter release priority for the first shot, AF/shutter release priority for the second and later shots in a burst, AF point selection the same/different for portrait/landscape orientations, default AF point in auto tracking modes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you're shooting with Canon cameras, the manual will usually contain a graph showing you the relation ship between the brightness (EV) of the scene, the shutter speed and aperture[[1](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/camera_settings/shooting_modes.do)]. In general, the camera will attempt to maintain a shutter speed that minimizes the effect of camera shake. For example, if you have a 50mm f/1.4 lens the camera will attempt to maintain a shutter speed of 1/60s. It will keep the aperture open at the maximum f/1.4 until the light levels are bright enough that stopping down will still allow a shutter speed of 1/60s or faster. As light levels increase, the rate at which the shutter speed is increased and the aperture stopped down follows the "program line" described in your camera's manual.

Basically, P-mode attempts to keep the shutter speed fast enough to alleviate the effects of camera shake. Only once that shutter speed can be achieved will the camera think of stopping down the lens. This mirrors my experience with Pentax and Canon cameras.

Note: I don't know how Auto ISO fits in with this scheme. From my observation, it seems that my camera attempts to keep the ISO as low as possible in order to maintain the aforementioned aperture/shutter speed ratio.

Comment: More or less true for Canon in the mid-2000s. The models are much more complex with many more variables today. Even so, Canon (and Nikon as well) seem to operate under the idea that their most advanced customers don't use **P** mode anyway.